# Fazer LI aparecer apenas no Mobile

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho um LI e gostaria que ela fosse mostrada apenas no modo mobile:

```
<ul style="display: block;">
 <li><a href="/">Início</a></li>
 <li class="list-cat"></li>
 <li><a href="teste">Preços</a></li>
 <li><a href="teste">Cases</a></li>
 <li><a href="teste">Sobre</a></li>
 <li><a href="teste">Contato</a></li>
 <li class="showMobile"><a href="teste">Mostrar apenas Mobile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Existe a possibilidade de fazer isso com JQuery?
Já tenho alguns tamanhos de tela que mobiles usam no meu arquivo CSS, nos **medias**.

Comment: Você usa o Bootstrap ? Ele tem classes especificas para isto ...

Comment: Não uso. Fiz eu mesmo.

Comment: Você não pode usar as Medias queries, quer jQuery mesmo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você poderia criar um css assim:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .showMobile{
    display:block;
  }
}
@media (min-width:480px)  {
  .showMobile{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

[veja funcionando no Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWpWvp)

Answer (score 3):

Como você pediu com JQuery e não MediaQuerie, eu resolvi o problema dando um get na largura da tela e setando o display como block caso esteja dentro da largura que você considera mobile. Existem inumeras formas de fazer isso com JQuery acredito que essa seja a mais simples !

```js
$(".showMobile").css("display", "none"); //Desabilitando

var mobileWidth = 300; //Set no tamanho que você considerar mobile

//Habilitando se estiver dentro da largura que você deseja
if ($(window).width() < mobileWidth) {
        $(".showMobile").css("display", "block")
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="display: block;">
 <li><a href="/">Início</a></li>
 <li class="list-cat"></li>
 <li><a href="teste">Preços</a></li>
 <li><a href="teste">Cases</a></li>
 <li><a href="teste">Sobre</a></li>
 <li><a href="teste">Contato</a></li>
 <li class="showMobile"><a href="teste">Mostrar apenas Mobile</a></li>
</ul>
```